# hosts file for ip address

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, routing, hosts

I would like to map ip address to specific localhost interfaces (e.g. 23.45.66.77 => 127.0.3.3). For named hosts I can use the hosts file. Naturally this doesn't work for IP address.

This has to work in windows, the only option I've found so far is implementing a TAP/TUN driver like openvpn does.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Can't you do this within routing table?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can you just change your software to use abcd.com instead of 23.45.66.77, that way it's easy to remap the IP?

Comment: I think your answer would be you would need a transparent proxy. But how to do that in windows is a problem! this guy got squid(a web proxy) with something like a transparent proxy of some kind. http://markus.revti.com/2009/01/squid-transparent-proxy-server-on-windows-server-2003/

Answer (score 1):

You could try Windows' NAT function: `netsh routing ip nat add addressmapping`

```
C:\> netsh
netsh> routing ip nat
netsh routing ip nat>
```

Comment: The following command was not found: routing ip nat

Answer (score 0):

Use a firewall and set a rule for all traffic to that IP address to be redirected locally/refused.

You could do this per machine (Software - Windows/Other Firewall eg Kaspersky) or network wide (Hardware - Outgoing Firewall, usually Router).

Answer (score -2):

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true

Review this resource. What you want to do is route the IP address to 127.0.3.3 and make sure to set it as permanent through the -p switch if you want it to survive a reboot.

Comment: Routing won't solve the problem.  The destination IP address in the packets will still be `23.45.66.77`, not `127.0.3.3` so the interface won't actually be able to receive the packet.

Comment: Good point. I'll have to rethink.

Comment: How about changing the ip address to that specific address through some kind of NAT based in Windows?